# Maze/Grid continued - Finding an optimal solution - memory/learning issue (JAVA)

Tags: java, game-physics, robot, maze

In relation to a previous questions found here: [Connecting a maze/grid's walls so all are interconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096066/connecting-a-maze-grids-walls-so-all-are-interconnected)

Currently my robot reads the grid location in front to the left, directly in front and in front to the right like so:

```
[00][01][02]
[10][11][12]
[20][^^][22]
```

[21] facing north would read [10][11][12] which may contain an object/trail its looking for.

There is a trail within my grid that I've made my robot able to follow around mapping the sensor inputs onto actions like so:

```
Sensor Actions:
000 =
001 = 
010 =
011 =
100 =
101 =
110 =
111 =
```

These can equal turnleft(), turnright(), goforward() or do nothing.

Currently it can find 14/15 of the trail pieces but cannot find the last piece which has a gap from the trail like so:

```
#KEY: x = empty, R = robot start position, T = trail

[x][x][x][x][x][x][x][x]
[x][x][x][x][x][x][T][x]
[x][x][x][x][x][x][x][x] <- Here is the gap!
[R][T][T][T][T][x][T][x]
[x][x][x][x][T][x][T][x]
[x][x][x][x][T][x][T][x]
[x][x][x][x][T][x][T][x]
[x][x][x][x][T][T][T][x]
```

The problem I have is when it reaches a gap in the trial it can't deal with it and ends up spinning pointlessly until it runs out of lifes.

I know I need to add in some form of memory or learning but I'm not sure what or how to implement this!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know for sure without your code, but it sounds like your robot is just lacking a way to move onto non-trail spaces. Assuming you've got something basically like this (pseudocode):

```
if (isTrailAhead) {
    moveAhead();
} else {
    turn();
}
```

Obviously this won't let you bridge gaps, because you'll keep spinning in circles without a trail to follow. There are a lot of ways you might go about dealing with this problem; the first two to come to my mind are:

1. Store a counter and increment it each time you look for a trail space and don't see one. If the counter gets above a certain number (say 4), just move straight ahead regardless of what's there (assuming that's possible). Reset the counter to 0 every time you move ahead.

   ```
   if (isTrailAhead) {
       moveAhead();
   } else {
       if (turnCounter > 4) {
           moveAhead();
       else {
           turn();
       }
   }
   ```

   Of course in this case you need an instance variable named turnCounter, and your moveAhead() and turn() functions should increment or reset this counter as appropriate.
2. In the pseudo-else-clause above (when you don't see a trail), generate a random number between 0 and 10. If it's greater than some predetermined number, move ahead if possible.

   ```
   if (isTrailAhead) {
       moveAhead();
   } else {
       if (new Random().nextInt(10) >= 8) {
           moveAhead();
       else {
           turn();
       }
   }
   ```

Basically, all you need is a way to break out of loops. Either of these should do the trick for you.